# Getting HTTP 502 on calling a time taking REST API using Python requests.post() method while same is working fine with REST client

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am calling a REST API which takes long time in processing like 2 minutes in python code using requests.post() method and getting HTTP 502 error in response. But calling same is working fine with different REST clients. What could be the possible reasons?
Following code has been used to call the API:

```
res = requests.post(url, proxies=proxies, headers=myheaders, data=data.encode('utf-8'), timeout=1000)
```

But for small inputs it works from python but not from long input. For big inputs it is giving HTTP 502 error. But everything is working fine with REST clients. What would be the possible point of error?

Comment: The upstream server didn't respond to proxy request. It's a server side error so most likely it couldn't handle the amount of data you post. If you own the server check the logs.

Comment: But when I post the same data using REST ciient then same server is responding properly.

Comment: Are you sure that the headers are exactly the same? Also, is your data a json payload? if yes, try sending it as `data=json.dumps(data)`.

Comment: Yes. It is working properly with samll data with same code but problem is with large data. with large it is giving HTTP 502 response.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue and found out that the issue was caused not because of the request body but as a result of the response body being too big.

I was using GraphQL to request data for the whole day and it kept on giving me 502 error. However, when I changed my request to provide the data only for 12 hours, it was successful in python.